# Why is weak convergence of bounded measures defined for $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

---

**Definition**: For any sequence of measures $(\mu_n)_n \subset M_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ where $M_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the space of bounded measures we say $(\mu_n)$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if for all $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ it holds that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f d\mu_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f d\mu$

---

My question or issue for discussion is that I wonder why we use $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ instead of say $f \in L_1$ since for bounded measures $L_1 (\mathbb{R}^d)$ contains almost all useful functions (including $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$).

An idea I also had was to e.g. have the definition with $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ since it lies dense in $L_1$.

What do you think of these ideas and why was this definition used as a standard instead?

Comment: It's not true that $L^1(\Bbb R)$ contains $C_b(\Bbb R)$. Apart from that the dual of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$, while the dual of $C_b$ can be naturally thought of as a space of measures

Comment: It is if the measure is bounded since you can bound the integral by $max_x |f(x)| \mu(\mathbb{R})$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: As shown in KRM's answer, by sending a point $x$ to the Dirac measure $\delta_x$ at $x$, you can see the original space inside that of probability measures. If you have a notion of convergence for measures, you can deduce one on the original space. So the convergence of measures is a topological notion. However, if you use $L^1$ functions, topology is nowhere to be seen in the new definition, i.e., the baby went with the bath water. The only (crucial) place where the topology enters is in the requirement that the functions be continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should note that what is  weak convergence for Probabilists is actually weak* convergence for Functional Analysists.

Consider the simple example $\mu_k=\delta_{1/k}$ (the delta measure at $\frac 1 k$) and $\mu=\delta_0$. Any reasonable definition of weak convergence should give $\mu_n \to \mu$. Now $f(\frac  1 k) =\int fd\mu_n \to f(0)= \int fd\mu $ if $f$ is continuous at $0$ but this fails if $f$ is just integrable.

Now consider $\mu_n =\delta_n$ and $\mu=0$. Then $\int fd\mu_n \to \int fd\mu$ for all $f \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ but not for all bounded continuous functions $f$. ($f\equiv 1$ for example).  In this case we don't want $\mu_n$ to converge to the zero measure so we don't want to use $C_c(\mathbb R)$  instead of $C_b(\mathbb R)$